# Why is reflexivity a feature of multi-step β-reduction, and not of β-reduction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, formal-languages, lambda-calculus

I understand the need to distinguish between two algorithms, even when one is enclosed in another. Transitivity as a feature of multi-step reduction makes perfect sense, since we literally need multiple steps of $\beta$-reduction execute it. What about reflexivity?

If I had to answer this question by myself, I would use a mathematician's point of view, saying that it is convenient to not have reflexivity in the definition of $\beta$-reduction, in order to prove certain propositions without having to deal with the case of reflexivity.

What would be the programmer's point of view?

EDIT: I am referring to untyped $\lambda$-calculus, sorry for not mentioning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the "computer scientist's point of view", a single step $\beta$-reduction roughly corresponds to an elementary step of computation. Thus, reaching a normal form (i.e. a term in the $\lambda$-calculus where $\beta$-steps cannot apply) means to evaluate a program to its output, i.e. to compute the final result.

Suppose that $\beta$-reduction were defined so as to be reflexive. What would be a normal form with such a definition? It would be really clumsy to define the notion of normal form, because for every term $M$, we have $M \to_\beta M$, which means that every term $M$ is not normal. And saying that $M$ is normal if and only if $M \to_\beta N$ implies $M = N$ does not solve the problem at all, because according to this attempt of definition the term $(\lambda x.xx) \lambda x.xx$ would be normal but actually  it $\beta$-reduces to itself by performing a "real" $\beta$-step, not thanks to reflexivity.

So, if the definition of $\beta$-reduction included reflexivity, it would be really clumsy to define the notion of normal form, which is the crucial notion corresponding to the idea of result of a computation.

Moreover, if you are interested in counting the number of steps to reach the normal form (i.e. to estimate the evaluation length), it would be impossible to do that if $\beta$-reduction were reflexive. For instance, if $M \to_\beta N$ by performing a "real" $\beta$-step and $\to_\beta$ is reflexive by definition, then
\begin{align*}
M &\to_\beta N \\
M &\to_\beta N \to_\beta N \\
M &\to_\beta N \to_\beta N \to_\beta N \\
M &\to_\beta N \to_\beta N \to_\beta N \to_\beta \dots\\
\end{align*}

where $N \to_\beta N$ because $\to_\beta$ is reflexive.
Said differently, if $M \to_\beta N$ by performing a "real" $\beta$-step, then $M$ $\beta$-reduces to $N$ with an arbitrary number of $\beta$-steps. Any quantitative analysis would be simply impossbible.

Comment: I never thought of it that way. Thanks for sparing the time to answer. So, multi-step β is a way of ensuring that we can reach a result(not necessarily NF), without knowing the number of steps, while "regular" β corresponds to an elementary step in the computation process.

Comment: @Jason - Yes, as a first intuition about $\beta$-reduction, you can say this.

Comment: @Jason - If an answer is clear enough, you can upvote it and accept it, as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Otherwise, you can ask for more explanation in the comments or editing your question.